# IIS Rewrite Module and Static Compression

Tags: iis

I've seen posts that say that you cannot use Static Compression in conjunction with IIS Rewrite Module Outbound rules.

In our configuration, we don't have any Outbound rules, just an Inbound rule (used to configure IIS as a reverse proxy)

Dynamic Compression works, but Static Compression does not work.

Can anyone confirm if Static Compression is disabled when using an Inbound rule?

- I've enabled Tracing and I cannot see any Static Compression failure messages
- Static Compression works if the rewrite rule is disabled.
- Windows Server 2012 / IIS 8.5

Below are snippets from the Trace logs from the Reverse Proxy site and the Downstream site (both running in IIS on the same machine).

In the Reverse Proxy site log you can see the StaticCompressionModule is loaded but immediately falls through to an NOTIFY_MODULE_END event. There are no entries for "STATIC_COMPRESSION_*" in this log.

This appears to indicate that Static Compression is not working for this site, even though it is enabled.

However, in the Downstream site you can see that the STATIC_COMPRESSION_START event is logged for the StaticCompressionModule. Shortly after there is a STATIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS (COMPRESSION_DISABLED) entry, but this is expected as Static Compression is disabled for this site.

**Trace Log (Reverse Proxy site)**

```
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{800000D4-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="OldHandlerName">StaticFile</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerName">ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerModules">ApplicationRequestRouting</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerScriptProcessor"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerType"></Data>
 </EventData>

 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{800000D4-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">StaticCompressionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">16</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-25T12:38:00.482Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{800000D4-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="5964" ThreadID="5132"/>
  <Computer>QA-CAMC01</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{800000D4-0001-FA00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">StaticCompressionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">16</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

**Trace Log (Downstream IIS site)**

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F800-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="OldHandlerName"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerName">StaticFile</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerModules">StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerScriptProcessor"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerType"></Data>
 </EventData>

     <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F800-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">StaticCompressionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">16</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x40</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-25T12:38:00.480Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000054-0000-F800-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="2548" ThreadID="3020"/>
  <Computer>QA-CAMC01</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000054-0000-F800-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>STATIC_COMPRESSION_START</Opcode>
```

Comment: It’s not disabled. You’ll need to identify not only if it’s failing, but also if it’s running at all using a full Failed Request Tracing log.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm already using the full Failed Request Tracing feature (on 200 status codes) and not seeing any Static Compression failure messages or any Static Compression start messages.

Comment: Make sure that the rewrite provider is also included in the trace. Go through all events and verify if any of them have something in the realm of complete request (sorry, don’t remember the exact wording). This would cause the pipeline to skip all the way to the LOG_REQUEST event, if I remember correctly.

Comment: I've expanded the description to include trace logs from both sites and it appears Static Compression is simply not doing anything on the Proxy site. Can you confirm please? @milope

Comment: I wonder if the reverse proxy side doesn’t execute static compression because the HTTP handler chosen is the URL Rewrite handler and not the Static File Handler. If my hypothesis is right, then it means all requests are being regarded as dynamic, in which only the dynamic compression module would be activated.

Comment: @milope I'm modified the log sample to show that the Proxy site switches the StaticFile handler to the ApplicationRequestRoutingHandler. Any thoughts how to get this working with Static Compression, or is a no-no?

Comment: I see the MAP_REQUEST_HANDLER notification which is way before compression should take place. It makes my hypothesis stronger that Static compression may be looking to find who’s the handler. Enable Dynamic compression and verify if conten is compressed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @milope - who identified the cause of the problem (see comments). The solution is to disable Static Compression on the Proxy site. Then 
enable Caching with Compression in the Application Request Routing Cache IIS module.